# Assertion at ..\mono\mini\unwind.c:620, condition `cfa_reg != -1' not met

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am getting this error in console screen and I can't play the project unless I fix it.

Can someone explain it and how to solve it? I can't find anything related to this error online.

I just started learning unity today. Every time I open it it's tells me **Mono.exe stopped working** but I don't know if it's related to the assertion error and also I uninstalled it then re-installed it again still nothing changed.

[image: the error]
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/compile-error-each-time-i-load-a-custom-package-or-plugin). It happens when you change the language of your computer to Arabic. I am not sure if any other language is affected.

There is no fix for this at this moment but the current **workaround** is to change the language back to English until this is fixed.

Go to *Control Panel* --> *Clock, Language, and Region* --> *Region*. Go to the *Administrative* tab then click the *Change system locale...* Button and change the language to *English (US )*.

Comment: yeah it even got rid off the mono.exe not working!!!
thank u so much it has no clue anywhere

Comment: Nice. FYI Visual Studio is free, you should consider using that for Unity and you won't run into problems like this one.

Comment: actually i'm already using it..and i ran into other problem with lines ending but solved it

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me, how is this a thing, why it's not already supported?????????!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @MousaAlfhaily Like I said in my answer, it's a bug in Unity. I don't have access to their source code so I can't tell what they did wrong. keep checking that link I posted, when the bug is fixed, that page should be updated.

Comment: @Programmer , yeah,  I hope they will fix it, it's not that big of a deal to be honest, the big deal for me is  that Arabic is not supported intentionally, and I hope not.

Comment: Unity wouldn't do such thing "intentionally". One thing to understand is that t's hard to make software that support every language.